# Embedding Java in Firefox 53+

Tags: java, firefox, java-web-start

After researching Java support in Firefox 53+ they dropped support on plugin NPAPI and recommend using Java Web Start. It seems like the only way to get Web Start to run is by having a link to the JNLP file which has you download the file and run it out of the browser. Is there anyway now or in the future Java will be able to be embedded in a webpage in Firefox 53+?

***Note:** I am aware that Firefox ESR exists, but to my knowledge they will be dropping Java Plugin support in early 2018. I have also read that IE and Safari will continue to support the Java Plugin, but I'm looking to run it embedded in Firefox 53+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway now or in the future Java will be able to be embedded in a webpage in Firefox 53+?

Short answer, no. Long answer nope.

See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).